# small python cards game program

Tags: python-2.7

I am a python beginner, try to write a small cards game code (just for play). The rules are as below:(1) 4 cards with number 1-10.
(2)any number must be used and can only be used once.
(3)only '+','-','*','/' can be used between two number
(4)List all the ways to get exact number '24', if there is no way, print 'no Way'.

I wrote some code, however, the result not satisfied, lots of repeated ways and treated '/' wrong (5/2 should be 2.5 not 2). Can anyone help.

```
import itertools
def braStr(string1):
    return '(' + string1 + ')'

def steps(input,list1 = []):
    if len(input)==2:
        list1.append(braStr(input[0]+ '+' + input[1]))
        list1.append(braStr(input[0]+ '-' + input[1]))
        list1.append(braStr(input[0]+ '*' + input[1]))
        list1.append(braStr(input[0]+ '/' + input[1]))
    else:
        for e in itertools.permutations(input):
            steps((braStr(e[0]+ '+' + e[1]),) + e[2:],list1)
            steps((braStr(e[0]+ '-' + e[1]),) + e[2:],list1)
            steps((braStr(e[0]+ '*' + e[1]),) + e[2:],list1)
            steps((braStr(e[0]+ '/' + e[1]),) + e[2:],list1)

while True:
    cards = raw_input("Please enter the 4 cards: ").split()
    if len(cards) != 4:
        print "you need 4 cards to begin!"

    list1 = []
    steps(cards,list1)
    result = False
    for e in list1:
        try:
            if eval(e) == 24:
                print e + '=', eval(e)
                result = True
        except:
            continue
    if result is False:
        print 'No way'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, one value should be in float.

```
>>> 5/3
1
>>> 5.0/3
1.6666666666666667
>>> 5/3.0
1.6666666666666667
```

You can convert value to float simply like,

```
>>> float(5)
5.0
```

if you are getting **repetition** in result, **append** the result to a **list** make it unique and print the unique ways of getting 24.